# How to change color of dates in table_calendar Flutter package?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, table-calendar

I was searching for how to change color of dates in Flutter, and couldn't end up with any solution. ChatGPT says its not even possible? :(
Does anyone here know how to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code, change color on your need  and refer [CalendarStyle](https://pub.dev/documentation/table_calendar/latest/table_calendar/CalendarStyle-class.html) and [defaultTextStyle](https://pub.dev/documentation/table_calendar/latest/table_calendar/CalendarStyle/defaultTextStyle.html)

```
TableCalendar(
   firstDay:DateTime.utc(2010, 10, 16),
   lastDay: DateTime.utc(2030, 3, 14),
   focusedDay: DateTime.now(),
   calendarStyle: CalendarStyle(
   defaultTextStyle:TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
   weekNumberTextStyle:TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
   weekendTextStyle:TextStyle(color: Colors.pink),
 ),
),
```

Result-> [image]

Comment: Thanks it works! Here is just one small change, to change weekend dates' color, following code works: weekendTextStyle: TextStyle(color: kSecondaryColor),